# Nested list: Ordering it into a dataframe

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

I have a list of nested lists. Each nested list is of different lengths. Each value in the lists has a name assigned to it. I would like to make a data frame from the lists, but order the lists so that each value is in the correct column in a data frame.

It's hard to explain in English, I hope this example code will explain:

```
list <- list(1,1:2,1:3)
names(list[[1]]) <- "a"
names(list[[2]]) <- c("c", "a")
names(list[[3]]) <- c("a","c","b")

table <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
colnames(table) <- c("a","b","c")  

> list
[[1]]
a 
1 

[[2]]
c a 
1 2 

[[3]]
a c b 
1 2 3 

> table
      a  b  c
[1,] NA NA NA
[2,] NA NA NA
[3,] NA NA NA
```

I want to order the lists into the table like so:

```
>table
          a  b  c
list[[1]] 1 NA NA
list[[2]] 2 NA  1
list[[3]] 1  3  2
```

so that the name of the value in the list matches the name of the column in the table, and `list[[1]]` goes to row 1, `list[[2]]` goes to row 2, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

(Additional Info:

My actual dataset has tens of thousands of nested lists, the longest list has length 26.

Im Running 32-bit R 3.2.4 on Windows 10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try `smartbind()` from `gtools` package in combination with `do.call()`.

```
library('gtools')
do.call("smartbind", list)
#  a  c  b
#1 1 NA NA
#2 2  1 NA
#3 1  2  3
```

Comment: I have been waiting for this answer without knowing it for a while, sir. +1.

Comment: Wow what a great function. Thank you, this worked perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You could turn them into data frames and use `data.table::rbindlist` which will work on lists of lists

edit 2 -- using the `gtools::smartbind` on the `rapply` works for a more complicated nested list of list:

```
list <- list(1,1:2,1:3)
names(list[[1]]) <- "a"
names(list[[2]]) <- c("c", "a")
names(list[[3]]) <- c("a","c","b")

list <- c(list(list, list(list)), list)

l <- rapply(list, function(x) data.frame(as.list(x)), how = 'list')
do.call(gtools::smartbind, l)

#   a  c  b
# 1 1  1  3
# 2 1  1  3
# 3 1 NA NA
# 4 2  1 NA
# 5 1  2  3
```

edit 1 -- this version might be more efficient

```
list <- list(1,1:2,1:3)
names(list[[1]]) <- "a"
names(list[[2]]) <- c("c", "a")
names(list[[3]]) <- c("a","c","b")

library('data.table')
list <- rapply(list, function(x) setDT(as.list(x)), how = 'list')

# [[1]]
#    a
# 1: 1
# 
# [[2]]
#    c a
# 1: 1 2
# 
# [[3]]
#    a c b
# 1: 1 2 3

rbindlist(list, fill = TRUE)[, c('a','b','c'), with = FALSE]

#    a  b  c
# 1: 1 NA NA
# 2: 2 NA  1
# 3: 1  3  2
```

original

```
list <- list(1,1:2,1:3)
names(list[[1]]) <- "a"
names(list[[2]]) <- c("c", "a")
names(list[[3]]) <- c("a","c","b")

list <- rapply(list, function(x) data.frame(as.list(x)), how = 'list')

# [[1]]
#   a
# 1 1
# 
# [[2]]
#   c a
# 1 1 2
# 
# [[3]]
#   a c b
# 1 1 2 3

data.frame(data.table::rbindlist(list, fill = TRUE))[, c('a','b','c')]

#   a  b  c
# 1 1 NA NA
# 2 2 NA  1
# 3 1  3  2
```

Comment: @llaffin if you have a more complicated nested list of lists, such as `list <- c(list(list, list(list)), list)` then combining both answers works well, ie, `l <- rapply(list, function(x) data.frame(as.list(x)), how = 'list'); do.call(gtools::smartbind, l)`. however, the `rbindlist` doesn't work for me on nested lists as advertised